# is there a way to block (specific) malicious scripts from running on my own webpage?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side

the problem is that some addons (or other 3rd parties) that run on users' end affect my site; change scripts, replace certain elements or in some way damage the user's experience.

what I wish to do is block specific js files (from other servers familiar to me) from being loaded or allow ONLY MY script files to load on my site.

I know I can remove a specific script tag from the dom after it's loaded but that does not resolve the issue since the code sticks in memory and runs anyway.

is there a way to initially code a page to do that?

Comment: This really makes no sense, how are script tags you don't want added to the site? Either you've been hacked, or you just remove the script tags on the serverside, they won't magically appear unless someone else has access to your server.

Comment: @Adeneo, I believe Yinon is talking about scripts people run in their browser with tools like Grease Monkey

Comment: @Yinon, what specific script are you talking about?  There might be a way to take counter measures, but I know of no general script buster solution.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean Daniel. scripts that run on users' browsers. like addons, commonly not initiated by users themselves.
any idea how?

Comment: sharing a thought. would it be possible to override the native appendChild function?
adding a condition to it might resolve the issue.
checking if element added is a script, and if so ask if its source is 'specificFile.js'. if the result is true avoid the execution of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by overriding the scope's "appendChild" function but saving it to a different function name.

in the overridden "appendChild" function I added conditions to make sure that no script with a certain blocked source (from an array list) will execute the original "appendChild" function.

hope that clears it.

```
var blockedUrlsArr = [
    'someUrl/malicious1.js',
    'someUrl/malicious2.js',
    'someUrl/malicious3.js'
];

function checkBlockedUrls(url) {
    var result = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < blockedUrlsArr.length; i++) {
        if (url.indexOf(blockedUrlsArr[i]) !== -1) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var originalAppendChild = Element.prototype.appendChild;

Element.prototype.appendChild = function () {
    if (arguments[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'script') {

        if (!checkBlockedUrls(arguments[0].src)) originalAppendChild.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    else originalAppendChild.apply(this, arguments);
};
```